# What does "cranked out with abandon" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I'm trying to understand this line –– *cranked out with abandon*. Does it mean that Fox produced lots of bad and cheap merchandise without any shame? Or it means something else?

> Season 8, which ran from October of 1996 to May of 1997, has more than
>   one episode that doesn’t quite fit with the rest of The Simpsons,
>   which may be why Season 8 has the feeling of a show that is winding
>   itself down. Starting all the way back in Season 1, with a joke about
>   cartoons being on in primetime, The Simpsons had always sent itself up
>   along with everything else. Whether it was laughing at its own
>   Thanksgiving parade float, describing its theme music as an “annoying
>   tune”, quickly glancing at the fourth wall, or making jokes about the
>   endless merchandise FOX **cranked out with abandon**, the show often found
>   lighthearted ways to poke fun at itself and its success.
>
> [source](https://deadhomersociety.com/zombiesimpsons/zs8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at two separate idioms:

- "Cranked out" - to produce something in large amounts.
- "With abandon": showing a complete lack of inhibition or restraint.

Your assessment of the phrase is pretty accurate - it means they mass-produced something with very little care or concern for quality.